# Zend Framework : Zend Dojo Data

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo, frameworks

I am using Zend Dojo Data by pulling data from a table with composite key (2 keys as primary key) as identifier. The Zend Dojo Data only allows to pass one key as identifier like setIdentifier ('Id'). What if my data set is based out of 'Id' and 'Name' as unique identifiers? setIdentifier('Id','Name') kind of function is available? Or do we have any work around ?

Zend Dojo Data [Reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.dojo.data.html)

Please guide.

Regards,
Subeesh

Comment: if two keys form a primary key than you could join(concatenate) the two keys into a single key. e.g key1 = 1 and key2 = 'hello'. Join them for a single key i.e key = key1 + '|' + key2  ( equals to '1|hello'). The pipe symbol is used as a key separator so that you can separate your keys if you want to. You could use any symbol as key separator.

Comment: Thank you frank.. From the above thought, I just had a different approach and fixed this issue. Once the data is fetched from database, manipulated it by adding an extra key with an incrementing integer value and used it as primary key and problem solved...